# Is there a Depth map data base?

Tags: machine-learning, graphics, neural-network, computer-vision

I want to know whether there is a pre existing data base of synthetic images and their associated depth maps for the purpose of training a NN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the Middlebury dataset:

http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/

And the NYU Depth dataset:

https://cs.nyu.edu/~silberman/datasets/nyu_depth_v2.html